# How to sort a list of tuples?

Tags: visualization, pattern-recognition, sorting

I am neither a mathematician, nor a computer scientist, but I have the following problem, which I cannot solve myself.

> I have $k$ $i$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, …, x_i)$, where $x ∈ [0,1]$.
>
> I need to order them so two most similar tuples are placed next to each other.
> The problem is I don’t really know how to define “similar” and what algorithm to use to order the tuples. This “similarity” of two tuples might be calculated (at least I believe so) by some kind of a function of the position of an element in a tuple and its value.

Below is an example of something I would like to have in the end, assuming that there are $10$ $6$-tuples $(x_A,x_B,x_C,x_D,x_E,x_F)$.

1. $(0.96,0,0,0,0,0.53)$
2. $(0.78,0.81,0.67,0,0,0)$
3. $(0,0.83,0.84,0.57,0,0)$
4. $(0,0.74,1,0,0,0)$
5. $(0,0,0.75,0.62,0.56,0,0)$
6. $(0,0,0.66,0.84,0.6,0,0)$
7. $(0.57,0,0,0.72,0.87,0.79)$
8. $(0,0.52,0,0,0.99,0.62)$
9. $(0.51,0.55,0,0.54,0.56,0)$
10. $(0.58,1,0,0.75,0,0.98)$

[Fig. 1A. Approximate visualization of a sorted list of $10$ $6$-tuples.]

[Fig. 1B. Approximate visualization of a sorted list of $k$ $i$-tuples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KJ3C.png)

[image]

Tuples #$9$ and #$10$ cannot be grouped/clustered, so they should be either discarded or moved to the end of a list.

As you can see, there should be a certain diagonal pattern, some sort of a main peak of density that moves. I would really appreciate if someone could at least point me in the right direction, I am completely clueless at the moment even about how to describe what I want in scientific terms.

Thank you very much. I really hope that someone would be able to help me.

P.S. I don’t know if it easier, but at the very least I can just transform all tuples in a way that all values in arrange $[0.51, 1]$ will be represented by $1$, and all values in a range $[0,0.5]$ will be represented by $0$.

Then I will need to sort the tuples so they formed the pattern below. Again, I don’t know what is the term for what I want. I expect to see some kind of a roughly diagonal pattern.

1. $(1,0,0,0,0,1)$
2. $(1,1,1,0,0,0)$
3. $(0,1,1,1,0,0)$
4. $(0,1,1,0,0,0)$
5. $(0,0,1,1,1,0)$
6. $(0,0,1,1,1,0)$
7. $(1,0,1,1,1,1)$
8. $(0,1,0,0,1,0)$
9. $(1,1,0,1,1,0)$
10. $(1,1,0,1,0,1)$

[Fig. 2. Approximate visualisation of a sorted list of $10$ simplified $6$-tuples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8PYA.png)

[image]

Comment: I think this is a difficult interesting question. I'm sure some computer science people have thought about it a lot. I searched for *arrange vectors in order of similarity* and found several links that might be of use. Similar searches might do better. Also consider asking on cross-validated instead of here (http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Except in 1D, there is no solution to this problem. Ordering and similarity are incompatible properties. There exist 'space-filling curves', but they address the issue very imperfectly. Depending  on your application, you should drop one of the requirements. I guess that you are more after 'data clustering'.

Comment: I think you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I have inferred correctly, what you are *trying* to do is not about sorting or similarity at all -- your goal is to rearrange the tuples (and possibly rejecting some of them) so that the values near the diagonal tend to be large, and the values away from the diagonal tend to be small. Is this accurate?

Comment: (question: does the "diagonal" have to be a straight line? In actual problems can the thick band be more curved than straight?)

Answer (score 1):

Idea for a solution, too long for a comment.

The data are $k$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. (I don't like $i$ for the dimension of the space). There are many ways to measure the distance between two such points; the Euclidean metric is the most natural, but others may be more appropriate for your problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions). Choose one. Calculate the distance between each pair of points.

Now you have the complete graph on $k$ points with a "distance" on each edge. One candidate for the vertex ordering (not sorting - @Hurkyl 's comment is right) you seek is a shortest path of $(k-1)$ edges that goes through each vertex. (There may be more than one such path.)
Unfortunately, that makes your problem sound very much like the notoriously difficult [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) .

Figure 1B suggests that both $k$ and $n$ (your $i$) are large, and of the same order of magnitude. That might be a problem. For example, if $k < n$ then you might be looking at something like a regular $k$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where every pair of points is distance $1$ apart and all orderings are equivalent and have total length $k$. Since the figure shows the pattern you expect, that may be because your data has some implicit structure you can take advantage of to find an approximate answer relatively quickly. Is the data behind Figure 1B real, or random? How did you choose the ordering to plot?

Note: it took me a little while to realize that the second plot, like the first, had discrete values for both axes, with color coding for the marked points in each row. It's not a scatter plot in the usual sense. I agree that it does represent visually what you are looking for.